# How to find if a char array exist in another char array without using string library?

Tags: c, arrays, character

I have two `char` arrays `char search_array[8]` and `input_array[30]` and I'm getting the characters by using `getchar`, but I want to find if the search array exists in input array without using string library.

Example:

search array: `hello`

input array `hello, how are you`

Comment: just write you own own function, what blocks you ?

Comment: @Martina: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

You need some string comparison loop, like that of which you can find in `strcmp` or `strcspn`. This is assuming you use a terminal value like C strings; if you use some length field you'll need to make adjustments to the loops to account for those clearly.[image] Here are some examples:

```
int strcmp(char const *x, char const *y) {
    while (*x && *x == *y) {
        x++;
        y++;
    }
    return ((unsigned)*x > (unsigned)*y) - ((unsigned)*x < (unsigned)*y);
}

size_t strcspn(char const *x, char const *y) {
    char const *x_ = x;
    while (*x_) {
        for (char const *y_ = y; *y_; y_++) {
            if (*x_ == *y_)
                return x_ - x;
        }
        x_++;
    }
    return x_ - x;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. There is a small bug in your `strcmp` implementation: the characters should be converted to `unsigned char` for comparison in the `return` statement. In `strcspn`, you should duplicate the `return` statement instead of using `goto`.

Comment: @chqrlie Hmmm.  Interesting OP choose the equivalent `(unsigned)*x > (unsigned)*y)`.  It  is the same result as `(unsigned char)*x > (unsigned char)*y)`.

Comment: @chux: interesting indeed! It seems to evaluate to the same result, but is not an elegant alternative.

Comment: @chqrlie Maybe not as elegant (as I first thought too) yet does have a potential advantage as many compilers emit better code using `int/unsigned` than `char` types.  Of course this is all micro-optimizations.

Comment: @chux: indeed micro-optimisations... But then `return (unsigned char)*x - (unsigned char)*y;` is even better on architectures where `UCHAR_MAX < INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution for your goal is to use the standard library's `strstr` function.

Since you are not allowed to use the *string library*, you should write your own version of `strstr` and use that.

Here is a simple yet conforming implementation:

```c
char *my_strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    for (;;) {
        for (size_t i = 0;; i++) {
            if (s2[i] == '\0')
                return (char *)s1;
            if (s1[i] != s2[i])
                break;
        }
        if (*s1++ == '\0')
            return NULL;
    }
}
```

You then use this function this way:

```
    if (my_strstr(input_array, search_array)) {
        printf("string was found\n");
    } else {
        printf("string was not found\n");
    }
```

Comment: The problem is, that I don't wanna use the string library, I'm not sure how to iterate over the arrays and check if the searched word is found in the input.

Comment: If you are allowed to write a function, you can write your own version of `strstr` and use it with `search_array` and `input_array`. If you are not allowed to write functions, you could duplicate the above code, initializing `s1` to point to `input_array` and `s2` to point to `search_array`...